# Implementation of the Dense Synthesizer

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, transformer-model

I’m trying to understand the Synthesizer paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.00743.pdf 1) and there’s a description of the dense synthesizer mechanism that should replace the traditional attention model as described in the Transformer architecture.

[image]

The **Dense Synthesizer** is described as such:

[image]

So I tried to implement the layer and it looks like this but I’m not sure whether I’m getting it right:

```
class DenseSynthesizer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, l, d):
        super(DenseSynthesizer, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(d, l)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(l, l)

    def forward(self, x, v):
        # Equation (1) and (2)
        # Shape: l x l
        b = self.linear2(F.relu(self.linear1(x)))   
        # Equation (3)
        # [l x l] x [l x d] -> [l x d]
        return torch.matmul(F.softmax(b), v)
```

Usage:

```
l, d = 4, 5

x, v =  torch.rand(l, d), torch.rand(l, d)

synthesis = DenseSynthesizer(l, d)
synthesis(x, v)
```

Example:

x and v are tensors:

```
x = tensor([[0.0844, 0.2683, 0.4299, 0.1827, 0.1188],
         [0.2793, 0.0389, 0.3834, 0.9897, 0.4197],
         [0.1420, 0.8051, 0.1601, 0.3299, 0.3340],
         [0.8908, 0.1066, 0.1140, 0.7145, 0.3619]])

v = tensor([[0.3806, 0.1775, 0.5457, 0.6746, 0.4505],
         [0.6309, 0.2790, 0.7215, 0.4283, 0.5853],
         [0.7548, 0.6887, 0.0426, 0.1057, 0.7895],
         [0.1881, 0.5334, 0.6834, 0.4845, 0.1960]])
```

And passing through a forward pass through the dense synthesis, it returns:

```
>>> synthesis = DenseSynthesizer(l, d)
>>> synthesis(x, v) 

tensor([[0.5371, 0.4528, 0.4560, 0.3735, 0.5492],
        [0.5426, 0.4434, 0.4625, 0.3770, 0.5536],
        [0.5362, 0.4477, 0.4658, 0.3769, 0.5468],
        [0.5430, 0.4461, 0.4559, 0.3755, 0.5551]], grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
```

**Is the implementation and understanding of the dense synthesizer correct?**

Theoretically, **how is that different from a multi-layered perceptron that takes in two different inputs and makes uses of it at different point in the forward propagation?**

Comment: Also asked on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/implementation-of-the-dense-synthesizer/79783

Comment: It looks correct. And yes, it is just a MLP. Not sure if this is the kind of answer you expect?

Comment: The problem is in the notation in eq. 2. At least for me, it is not clear how they perform the linear transformation. It could be `(d, l)` and `(l, l)`, just like in your implementation, or `(d, d)` and `(d, l)`. I think the latter might work better.

Comment: Also, `(d, d)` and `(d, l)` is more aligned with `QK^t` attention.

Comment: @MohammadArvan I think you are right on the (d,d)->(d,l), this matches the number of parameters of the dense variant in table 1

Answer (score 4):

**Is the implementation and understanding of the dense synthesizer correct?**

Not exactly, `linear1 = nn.Linear(d,d)` according to the paper and not `(d,l)`.
Of course this does not work if `X.shape = (l,d)` according to matrix multiplication rules.

This is because :

[image]
[image]

So `F` is applied to each  `Xi` in X for i in `[1,l]`

The resulting matrix `B` is then passed to the softmax function and multiplied by `G(x)`.
So you'd have to modify your code to sequentially process the input then use the returned matrix to compute `Y`.

**how is that different from a multi-layered perceptron that takes in two different inputs and makes uses of it at different point in the forward propagation?**

To understand, we need to put things into context, the idea of introducing attention mechanism was first described here in the context of Encoder - Decoder : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf

The core idea is to allow the model to have control over how the context vector from the encoder is retrieved using a neural network instead of relying solely on the last encoded state :

[image]

see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421935/what-exactly-are-keys-queries-and-values-in-attention-mechanisms) for more detail.

The Transformers introduced the idea of using "Multi-Head Attention" (see graph below) to reduce the computational burden and focus solely on the attention mechanism itself. [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421935/what-exactly-are-keys-queries-and-values-in-attention-mechanisms)

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf

[image]

[image]

***So where does the Dense synthesizer fits into all of that ?***

It simply replaces the Dot product (as illustrated in the first pictures in your post) by `F(.)`. If you replace what's inside the `softmax` by `F` you get the equation for `Y`

[image]

**Conclusion**

This is an MLP but applied step wise to the input in the context of sequence processing.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think the dense synthesizer attention mechanism is applied step wise to the input. It's applied all at once for all states in the input within the encoder/decoder block of the transformer architecture and not explicitly across the encoder to decoder.

Could you explain a little on the step-wise explanation?

Comment: @alvas, it's in the definition of `F`itself : "F(.), a parameterized function, for projecting input `Xi` from `d` dimensions to `l` dimensions".  `F(.)` is applied to each token in `X` and `F(Xi) = Bi`. Otherwise matrix shape are incompatible for multiplication.